# Can't correctly print data from JSON array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I've got this simple array of data in a json file but trying to extract the data is proving hard for a novice like me. Here is the array that I have been given.

```
var clients = [
{
    "clientid": "456489",
    "client-name": "John Smith",
    "email": "a.smith@gmail.com"        
},
{
    "clientid": "654987",
    "client-name": "Mark Barnes",
    "email": "barnesdog@gmail.com"
},
{
    "clientid": "987981",
    "client-name": "Taylor Johnson",
    "email": "taylor.j@gmail.com"
},
]
```

My first test was this to see if I could get a success message or not. It has not worked and i'm just not sure why.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $.getJSON("clients.json", function(data){
         $.each(data, function (index, value) {
             console.log(data);
         });
     });
});
```

I know this is simple, but I have never done this before, thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(data)` before the loop?

Comment: I get nothing again, which means it's not getting into the getJSON for some reason.

Comment: Any error in console? Check in network tab whether the url is getting resolved fine

Comment: Your clients.json file should not have the var clients = part

Comment: That's what the client, who are dev team, have given me?

Comment: Your JSON file is not valid. You either need to export that var from the file or change the file to be valid JSON

Answer (score -1):

Are you using Chrome and opening the HTML file that contains the code from file? By default Chrome does not allow this. Try it in Firefox, if that works that was the issue. This will not happen if your HTML file is on a server in the web.

Comment: I'm using a local server in Chrome

Comment: If you are using a local server and not a file then Chrome is not the issue. As the previous comments stated though your json file needs to be valid. E.g. you have an extra comma after the last entry in the array. Use [JSONlint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate the contents of the .json file.

Answer (score -1):

removing the trailing `,` from the list of objects in json and `var clients =` from the top and it should work.